# Mixing Bootstrap classes and ignoring style

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a carousel that I made with the help of bootstrap. I am trying to replace the carousel-indicators (the "dot navigation") with a navbar. This is the code for the standard dot-navigation

```
        <!-- Indicators dot nav -->
        <ul class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ul>
```

I have replaced that with this navbar:

```
<!-- Navigation bar controls -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ol class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active" data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="0"><a>slide 1</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item" data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="1"><a>slide 2</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item" data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="2"><a>slide 3</a></li>
            </ol>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

The problem is, I want to maintain the functionality of the carousel-indicators class. To do this, I can add carousel-indicators to the ol like this:

`<ol class="nav navbar-nav carousel-indicators">`

But this obviously alters the style of the navbar, and it becomes quite complicated to fix. I can fix it very cleanly and simply by altering a line of code in the bootstrap javascript in the carousel class from this:

```
this.$indicators = this.$element.find('.carousel-indicators')
```

to this

```
this.$indicators = this.$element.find('.nav')
```

And that fixes my problem, but this feels very improper. What is the correct way to go about fixing this?

Comment: You're right, it's not recommended to modify the bootsrap files because this will break when updating the library. However, given the nature of what you're trying to do, this can be the best approach, otherwise you'll have to fix the complicated CSS as you said.